# Share Records Insufficient Privileges

Tags: apex, trigger, insufficient-privileges, sharerecord

I have a trigger on a custom object that inserts a share record after the insert of the custom object record.

When I go to insert the Share record, I get an `INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY` error. I can understand that this would happen to the custom object record because the org wide defaults are set to private but why would this be happening to the Share record? Is there an additional step I need to take to be able to insert the Share record?

The trigger has to be an after insert to be able to associate the custom object record to the share record.

```
trigger SingleShareRecord on SG_you__c (after insert) {

if (Trigger.isInsert) {
    if (Trigger.isAfter) {
        List<SG_you__Share> sharesToCreate = new List<SG_you__Share>();
        for (SG_you__c ex : Trigger.new) {
            SG_you__Share sg = new SG_you__Share();
            sg.ParentId = ex.Id;
            sg.AccessLevel = 'Edit';
            sg.UserOrGroupId =  ex.CreatedById;
            sharesToCreate.add(sg);
        }
        
        if (!sharesToCreate.isEmpty()){
            Database.SaveResult[] srList = Database.insert(sharesToCreate);
            
            // Process the save results.
            for (Database.SaveResult sr : srList) {
                if (sr.isSuccess()) {
                    system.debug('success');
                } else {
                    // Get first save result error.
                    Database.Error err = sr.getErrors()[0];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't the user you are sharing with already have edit access to the record unless you are changing the owner in a before trigger.

Comment: I think mahjit right. Your code probably try to provide sharing 'Edit' to the record owner. And since he already have full access, you cannot do it.
It can be good approach to always verify you are not providing sharing access to the record owner.
E.g: if(record.ownerId != [userIdGettingAccess]) ==> Add new Share record

Comment: you are right, thank you. They owner of the record already has access and so I was trying to provide access again.